# In ASP.NET MVC, what internal method is used to encode textbox contents

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Given a model with the text `\" &`, this will render in the View in a textbox as `&quot; &amp;`. What internal mechanism is used to do this?

[edit, clarifying]

I have a model with this value

```
public string Name { get; set; } = "\" & <script></script>";
```

This renders in a textbox with

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

which renders on a view like so

```
<input ... value="&quot; &amp; <script></script>" aria-invalid="false">
```

(I removed the class, etc)

So the quote and ampersand were encoded but the script wasn't.

Similarly if you have this

```
<span>@Html.Raw(Model.Name)</span>
```

It becomes:

```
<span>" &amp; <script></script></span>
```

I'm seeing this via edit as html in the developer tools.

My confusion is, what is encoding the ampersand. Is it `Html.Raw`, is it the browser itself?

Just to add to my confusion. If you use view source

The input box shows as

```
value="&quot; &amp; &lt;script>&lt;/script>"
```

the `<` is encoded but not the `>`

While the span shows as

```
<span>" &</span>
```

Comment: Why are you asking? And what code are you using to do this? That's HTML encoding and will appear just fine on any browser. ASP.NET doesn't encode text when it knows it will be used as plain text, eg during data binding. It *will* encode raw output attempts. The way to change this is to fix the code, not disable HTML encoding

Comment: There are ways to emit raw strings anyway, eg `Html.Raw`. Post your code, the current and expected output

Comment: In a textbox the & is encoded, something like <script> isn't, so it isn't html encoding. It's specifically what happens in a textbox I'm trying to get to the bottom of

Comment: Post the code in the question itself, don't describe it in the comments. Browsers have no problem with HTML encoding. They depend on it. If a textbox appears weird it's because the text does something unusual.

Comment: Are you sure your original text doesn't already contain encoded text?

Comment: As for if `&nbsp;` is HTML encoding or not, there's no debate. That's the [HTML entity](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) for the space character in HTML Encoding. No ifs or buts or maybes. It doesn't matter which code performed the encoding, or whether the original code already contained `&nbsp;`.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you want. What you posted would be invalid HTML unless encoded so yes, it **MUST** be encoded. If you emitted that raw string you'd end up with `<input ... value=""` followed by `& <script></script>" aria-invalid="false">` The value would be an empty string and the input tag would have a bunch of invalid markup

Comment: I want to understand the mechanism whereby you can post data like "&<script>"in a textbox to the server, have it return and be posted again, and this is the key bit, without getting the data being doubly encoded.

Comment: A Razor page doesn't emit raw strings to the HTTP response. It's used to generate rendering code in the backend that produces valid HTML. That code includes code that generates all the tags in the page. [Html.Raw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) returns an [HtmlString](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/HtmlString.cs) The source code shows that `HtmlString` *doesn't* encode anything though.

Comment: Yes, the browser can easily encode that text even if it came from the server. This is done to ensure the `value` is valid. If the *real* question is how to create an HTML edit box or just be able to enter script code, the answer is to do it in a way acceptable by the browser, not try to disable encoding. There are several answers for this too, as all programming forums and sites, including StackOverflow, require this.

Comment: The real question is my trying to understand the mechanism so I can ensure I am avoiding XSS better. By default ASP.NET MVC will show an error message if you try to postback <script>. I'd like to disable this to enable users to post code, but clearly I'm not going to do this without a clear understanding of how the encoding works, which I don't presently have. I'm looking for an ASP.NET MVC specific answer

Comment: there's no ASP.NET specific answer to a generic HTML question. This has nothing to do with disabling encoding or putting your users at risk. It has to do with understanding how to use the correct tags and attributes for the job. You don't think StackOverflow disables XSS in its editor? The very part that's most vulnerable to it? Had you done what you wanted, your own tag would break

Comment: One way to input code in a form is to use `textarea`. Another is to set the `contenteditable` tag in a div. In both cases you're dealing with blocks, not attribute values. You can easily check how other sites do this through the F12 developer tools - just inspect the code edit sections. There are code-editing scripts and components that take care of editing, correcting, colorizing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding in an asp.net application is configurable, via the [HttpRuntime.EncoderType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.encodertype?view=netframework-4.8.1) setting in web.config. The default for this setting depends on the version of Visual Studio used to create the application.

This setting (which is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977059/what-is-the-benefit-to-make-encodertype-to-antixssencoder-in-a-mvc-application)) causes your application to use the [AntiXssEncoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder?view=netframework-4.8.1) to encode everything.

```
<system.web.>
    <httpRuntime encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder,System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</system.web>
```

Under the covers, rendering methods (such as those in `HttpServerUtility`) end up calling the methods in this class.

Comment: I think this is the answer, I'll look into it later and mark it as so if that's the case. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

For Razor based pages can use [`HtmlHelper.Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2):

```
@Html.Raw(your_string_with_special_symbols);
```

Comment: @tony why do you assume it converts anything? Do you have an actual example? Post it in the question. You're making an extraordinary claim that contradicts both the docs and other developers' experience over the past 10+ years. That needs pretty clear evidence

Comment: I can see this is making it more confusing. Stack overflow won't let me close it, I'll add more content

Comment: @tony if you asked a colleague sitting next to you the same vague question what would be their answer? `Show me the code`.